# Can't remove page number with \thispagestyle{empty} or \pagenumbering{gobble}

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, newlfm

I'm using the template available [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/press-release) but it shows a `1 of 1` page numbering at the bottom. I'm trying to remove it to no avail.

Adding `\pagenumbering{gobble}` removes the numbers but the output still prints "of" at the bottom. Adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` removes the "of" like I want but also removes the logo at the top generated by:

```
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Cheader{\vspace{16pt}\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{logo.png}}}
\lthUiuc
```

So I'm out of ideas now and could not find any other solution. Could anyone please help?

Here is a stripped down version of the tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,pressrelease]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Cheader{\vspace{16pt}my title}} 
\lthUiuc 
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
my body
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

If you add `\thispagestyle{empty}` right before `\end{newlfm}` then the page number together with the "of" disappears together with the "my title" on top.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}` to help us reproduce your situation. And usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [newlfm document class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) provides the `\Cfooter` marco which you can use to set the central footer. However, the footers are reset when you start a `newlfm` environment.
You can get around this by placing `\Cfooter` inside the `newlfm` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,pressrelease]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}
\newcommand{\subtitle}{This is a subtitle.}
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Cheader{\vspace{16pt}my title}}
\lthUiuc
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\Cfooter{}
abc
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need the definition of `\subtitle` in order to make the example compile.

Answer (score 3):

A global removal of this is possible via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\PhrMore}{\@gobble}{}{}% Remove page numbering within newlfm
\PhrMore{}% Reset (centered) footer to be empty.
\makeatother
```

`\PhrMore{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} \Cfooter{\@more@phr}\cfooter{\@more@phr}` is executed when in `pressrelease` mode, setting the footer to contain the "X of Y" page numbering. The above patch gobbles this argument and resets it to be empty `{}` (otherwise defaulting to `--- more ---`.